# Pre-flight request returns 404 only on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, xmlhttprequest, cors, istio

I am trying to access a resource on my website through Chrome, for which the browser performs a pre-flight OPTIONS request. This pre-flight request works fine in Firefox and even using cURL, but for some reason returns a 404 status in Chome. I am currently on Chrome v81.0.4044.129 on macOS version 10.15.4. See details below.

**Console logs**

```
OPTIONS https://sub.my.website.com/v1/resource 404
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sub.my.website.com/v1/resource' from origin 'https://my.website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.​
```

**Request headers**

```
:authority: sub.my.website.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /v1/resource/
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: authorization
access-control-request-method: GET
dnt: 1
origin: https://my.website.com
referer: https://my.website.com/v1/overview
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
```

**cURL request & headers**

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://my.website.com" \               
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization' \
    -H 'Referer: https://my.website.com/v1/overview' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'DNT: 1' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' \
    "https://sub.my.website.com/v1/resource"
```

**​cURL​​ response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-origin: https://my.website.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,HEAD,CONNECT
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-max-age: 86400
date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 10:32:17 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0
```

​Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!